# Series expansion of QPochhammer symbol

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Mathematica has an internal function QPochhammer[a,q,n] which is given by
$$\text{QPochhammer}[a,q,n]=\frac{\text{QPochhammer}[a,q]}{\text{QPochhammer}[a q^n,q]}=\frac{\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-a q^k)}{\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-a q^{n+k})}.$$

While I can series expand QPochhammer[q,q], I get the following when I try to expand QPochhammer[q,q,n].

```
In[1220]:= Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 2], {q, 0, 3}]

Out[1220]= SeriesData[q, 0, {
 1, Derivative[0, 1, 0][QPochhammer][0, 0, 2] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][
   QPochhammer][0, 0, 2], 
  Rational[1, 2] (
   Derivative[0, 2, 0][QPochhammer][
    0, 0, 2] + 2 Derivative[1, 1, 0][QPochhammer][
     0, 0, 2] + Derivative[2, 0, 0][QPochhammer][0, 0, 2]), 
  Rational[1, 6] (
   Derivative[0, 3, 0][QPochhammer][
    0, 0, 2] + 3 Derivative[1, 2, 0][QPochhammer][
     0, 0, 2] + 3 Derivative[2, 1, 0][QPochhammer][
     0, 0, 2] + Derivative[3, 0, 0][QPochhammer][0, 0, 2])}, 0, 4, 1]
```

Is there a way to express this in terms of polynomials of q, and not have Derivative of QPochhammers?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series might not make fully sense as it is already a polynomial:

```
QPochhammer[q, q, 2] // FunctionExpand
```

gives:

```
(1 - q) (1 - q^2)
```

If I input your code I get:

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 2], {q, 0, 3}]
```

Gives:

```
1-q-q^2+q^3+O[q]^4
```

in version 12.3.1.

Comment: But it would be much more interesting to expand `Series[QPochhammer[q, q, n], {n, Infinity, 1}]` which is returned unevaluated.

Comment: I think this might not be possible since it is alternating:
```DiscretePlot[QPochhammer[6, 6, n], {n, 0, 10}]```

Comment: I meant case `0 < q < 1`, try 1/6 instead of 6.

Comment: ```Limit[QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6, n], n -> \[Infinity]]``` becomes ```QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6]``` so this becomes just a constant for the case that 0<q<1. But Mathematica will (in general) assume that q can be anything including complex numbers…

Comment: Yes, but I would be interested in expansion `QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6, n] = QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6] + c/6^n + ...`, numerically, `c = 0.1611375456324329881847500430992597937835995257387...`

Comment: The next term in this expansion is `... + c2/6^(2*n) + ...`, where `c2 = 0.027623579251274226545957150245587393220045632983791772300083...`

Comment: In closed form, `QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6, n] / QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6] = 1 + 1/(5*6^n) + 6/(175*6^(2*n)) + ...`, it would be good if Mathematica could generate this.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec
Is this the result you are looking for?

`Series[AsymptoticRSolveValue[y[n] == QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6, n]/QPochhammer[1/6, 1/6] //FunctionExpand, y[n], {n, \[Infinity], 5}] /. n -> Log[6, 1/x] // Simplify, {x, 0, 5}] /. x -> 6^n // Normal`

Giving a result of

`1+6^n/5+(6 (6^n)^2)/175+(216 (6^n)^3)/37625+(46656 (6^n)^4)/48724375+(60466176 (6^n)^5)/378832015625+O[6^n]^6`

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Fixing minor issues,
`(Series[AsymptoticRSolveValue[y[n]==QPochhammer[1/6,1/6,n]/QPochhammer[1/6,1/6]//FunctionExpand,y[n],{n,\[Infinity],5}]/.n->Log[6,1/x]//Simplify,{x,0,5}]//Normal)/.x->6^-n`

Giving a result of

$\frac{6^{10-5 n}}{378832015625}+\frac{6^{6-4 n}}{48724375}+\frac{6^{3-3 n}}{37625}+\frac{1}{175} 6^{1-2 n}+\frac{6^{-n}}{5}+1$

Comment: @Nugi: Yes, thank you!!!

Comment: You just need to replace `Simplify` with `FullSimplify` so that the result is in the correct form also for q = 1/2 or q = 1/3. `With[{q = 1/2}, Normal[Series[FullSimplify[AsymptoticRSolveValue[FunctionExpand[ y[n] == QPochhammer[q, q, n]/QPochhammer[q, q]], y[n], {n, Infinity, 5}] /. n -> Log[1/q, 1/x]], {x, 0, 5}]] /. x -> q^n]`